# jQuery AJAX tomar valor de una lista y pasarlo a un objeto

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo el siguiente `@Html.DisplayFor`, ¿cómo podría hacer para tomar el ID y pasarlo a un objeto de AJAX?

```
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Regla, new { id = "reglaid" })  

       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input id="botonformularios" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"  />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Intenté con las siguientes líneas pero cuando lo paso al controlador me figura como `null`:

```
 $("#botonformularios").click(function () {
     var obj = {               
         Rid:$("#reglaid").children("input").val(),
         Result: $("#result").parents().children("input").val(),                        
      }
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          contentType: false,
          url: "/ZsvalWorkflow/Create",
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data: JSON.stringify(obj),
          success: function (data) {
              alert(data)
          },
      });
  })
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porque utilizas  `$("#reglaid").Children("input").val()` ? no debería obtenerlo por el id directamente? `$("#reglaid").Val()` ya que el selector va x id.

Comment: Estas seguro de que displayFor asigna un id a sus elementos? si no mal recuerdo displayFor no crea nisiquiera una etiqueta span... corrigeme si me equivoco.
PS: si no es así, y genera un span o != elemento tipo input, entonces podrias acceder al valor con $(selector).html();

Comment: Tal cual como dice @JohnTrack el `DisplayFor` etiquetas cuando los datos son de tipo primitivo, por lo tanto no le agrega ese id. Lo que puedes hacer es encerrar el contenido de ese `DisplayFor` y agregarle el id. luego seleccionarlo como te indica John.

Answer (score 2):

[DisplayFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) genera html basandose en las propiedades de un objeto (por lo general son varios div si es una clase y un elemento si es un valor) pero en tu caso me imagino que solo quieres tomar el valor de una sola propiedad e imprimirlo.

En esos casos lo que se genera en el html es un elemento de **tipo texto** así que la solución en tu caso es escribir un div alrededor y asignarle un id u otro tipo se selector para poder identificarlo y seleccionarlo con jQuery. Tu código quedaría así:

```
<div id="reglaid">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Regla.Rid)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
         <input id="botonformularios" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"  />
     </div>
</div>
```

Y luego en tu script lo localizas por el id

```
$("#botonformularios").click(function () {
     var obj = {               
         Rid:$("#reglaid").text(),
         // Resto del código
})
```

Ten en cuenta que si usas razor en tu script estas obligado a mantenerlo siempre dentro del cshtml por eso en mi respuesta te recomiendo usar esta variante. Usando jquery puedes mover tu script sin problemas a un fichero separado en el momento en que tu código comienze a crecer.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deberias determinar es como renderiza en html el DisplayFor(), recuerda que este se basa en template para determinar el resultado en el browser. Podrias usar las Developer Tools (accediendo con F12) para inspeccionar la pagina y determinar que tag genera.

Una vez que determinar el tag podrias aplicar el selector de jquery que permita recuperar el valor.

Si renderiza a un div o span, en jquery usarias el [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/), o sea

```
var regla = $("reglaid").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu código no estás asignando el valor de `obj.Id` es por esto que llega como 0 al *action*

Asumiendo que en el modelo tienes el `Id` como propiedad del modelo y que el código javascript esté dentro de una vista Razor:

```
$("#botonformularios").click(function () {
    var obj = {
        Id: @Model.Id, // o el valor que necesites              
        Rid:$("#reglaid").children("input").val(),
        Result: $("#result").parents().children("input").val(),                        
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        url: "/ZsvalWorkflow/Create",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
    });
})
```